# Update sharepoint user profile inside an AD group

Tags: sharepoint-2010, active-directory, user-permissions, user-profile

The context:

A client environment: SharePoint Foundation 2010

He wants to have a timerjob to update users profiles with data in active directory. Everything OK, I developed the timerjob that gets a catalog from active directory & updates selected fields for every user in the SharePoint hidden users list, that way I can keep a daily update for every user.

The problem: the client has used (as i should have thought) an active directory group that he have to manage permissions in SharePoint something like "All authenticated users".

Now i have no clue on how to update the profiles inside that group because they don't exist in the list.

Any ideas on where to update those profiles ?

Comment: So I have a -1 because chrome mobile removed my new lines? Woa.. this is a hard audience

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the SP site was upgraded from an earlier flavor - specifically 2007 - and this is an artifact of that-  NT Authority All Authenticated Users.....    This is a catch-all reference sometimes dropped into a group or a listing pointing towards the SP site admin for user access requests.  You can control access on it by having it in one group and then setting the permissions of that group as low as possible.  But as for reading anything back into your scheme from Active Directory - there's nothing to grab.  It's only a flag that tells SharePoint that an ID authenticated within the windows domain and nothing more. It's a default gateway of sorts to allow domain users into the SharePoint site, usually, for read only access or access to request SharePoint unique permissions, or, on some sites, access at a basic visitor level.